# How to interpret the given preorder and inorder nodes to form a postorder node?

Tags: tree, binary, binary-tree

I am unsure how the traversal works and the order it presents

consider the traversal of a tree

preorder --> ABCEIFJDGHKL
Inorder --> EICFJBGDKHLA

Which of the following is correct post order traversal?

A)    EIFJCKGLHDBA

B)     FCGKLHDBUAE

C)    FCGKLHDBAEIJ

D)     IEJFCGKLHDBA

I tried drawing out the diagram but it was not the same order as the question presents

Comment: Any feedback to the answer(s) below?

Answer (score 0):

A preorder sequence always lists the root first, so the root of the tree is A. Since a postorder would have to list the root **last**, we can already strike out the potential answers (B) and (C), as those do not have A in the last position.

An inorder first lists the nodes of the root's left subtree, then the root, then the nodes of the right subtree. As A occurs last in the inorder sequence, all other nodes are in the left subtree.

This means the left subtree has a preorder sequence of BCEIFJDGHKL (the original preorder without A), and therefore B is its root. So we have:

```
   A
  / \
 B   -
```

**Expanding B:** In the inorder sequence we find B halfway, and so its left subtree consists of EICFJ and its right subtree of GDKHL. The preorder lists the left subtree as CEIFJ, and so C is the root of that subtree. The preorder lists the right subtree as DGHKL so D is the root of that subtree. This gives us:

```
     A
    /
   B
  / \
 C   D
```

**Expanding C:** In the inorder sequence EICFJ, the position of C indicates that its left subtree consists of EI and its right subtree of FJ. The preorder for EI is also EI, so E is the left child of C. The preorder for FJ is also FJ, so F is the right child of C:

```
       A 
      /
     B
    / \
   C   D
  / \
 E   F
```

**Expanding E and F:** In the inorder sequence EI, the position of E indicates that I is its right child. In the inorder sequence FJ, the position of F indicates that J is its right child:

```
       A 
      /
     B
    / \
   C   D
  / \
 E   F
  \   \
   I   J
```

**Expanding D:** In the inorder sequence GDKHL (see "expanding B"), the position of D indicates that G is its left child, and KHL are the nodes in its right subtree. The preorder for KHL is HKL, and so H is the root of the right subtree:

```
        A 
       /
     _B_
    /   \
   C     D
  / \   / \
 E   F G   H
  \   \
   I   J
```

**Expanding H:** In the inorder sequence KHL has H in the middle, so it is clear where the remaining K and L should be placed

```
        A 
       /
     _B_
    /   \
   C     D
  / \   / \
 E   F G   H
  \   \   / \
   I   J K   L
```

At this point you can visually confirm that this tree has the given preorder and inorder traversals. We can also read the postorder traversal, which is IEJFCGKLHDBA, and so the correct answer is option (D).